# Use i in var name on a for cicle

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is not working but I have no idea how to correct it:

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
    var address_con+[i] = document.getElementById("address_con[i]")
    var CAP_con+[i] = document.getElementById("CAP_con[i]")
    var city_con+[i] = document.getElementById("city_con[i]")
}
```

It should produce:

```
//FIRST ELEMENT
address_con1 = document.getElementById("address_con1")
etc.
//LAST ELEMENT
city_con3 = document.getElementById("city_con3")
```

The error is on:

```
var name+[i]
```

Thank you

Comment: You'll have an infinity loop with that loop statment. change to `for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: @limelights Actually I think most browser will correct that automatically, but the OP should still probably change that

Comment: Chrome broke down when I ran it, so I guess not.

Comment: @lime Oh, okay then :P

Comment: The i=3 was an error I made as I wrote the loop here. SORRY....
I'm trying to insert the i on the vars names.

Answer (score 2):

There is no replacement of variables inside Strings in JavaScript (unlike in PHP, where this is possible). Similar for creating new variables, which you can't do in the way, you are trying.

To get your naming, you can use the following code, which will store all your values inside the `result` variable.

```
var result = {};
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
    result[ "address_con" + i ] = document.getElementById("address_con" + i)
    result[ "CAP_con" + i ] = document.getElementById("CAP_con" + i)
    result[ "city_con" + i ] = document.getElementById("city_con" + i)
}
```

Comment: @user2120569 corrected the answer and added some explanation.

Comment: So there is no solution to generate 9 vars with 9 names? I appreciate your solution, but at this point it's faster to write the 9 variables manually...

Comment: @user2120569 Depends on where you need those variables. You could replace `result` with `window` inside the loop and have those variables created in the global scope, which is directly accessible. However, I would not recommend this approach as it pollutes the global namespace unnecessarily. What is wrong with using `result` later on?

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition in the for loop

```
for(i=1; i=3; i++)
```

Will always get you out of the loop, I think you should try the following code instead:

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that? I mean i = 1 and then  you try and check the condition (which is actually an assignment!)